# Selenium vba: Found Multiple elements with same Class Name (pulling incorrect table details)

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Team, I  have a code which previously pulled table data correctly, now the webpage have been updated with several codes hence it result in pulling different table data in between my work.

I need to get the first image table excluding second table.

Current code i used

```
Option Explicit
Sub Testing()

Dim Dr As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim hTable, hBody, hTR, hTD, tb As Object
Dim bb, tr, td As Object
Dim r, c, lr1 As Long
    
        Dr.Get "url"
        Dr.Wait (5000)
        With Sheet1
            .Activate
            Set hTable = Dr.FindElementsByCss(".table")
            For Each tb In hTable
                Set hBody = tb.FindElementsByTag("tbody")
                For Each bb In hBody
                    Set hTR = bb.FindElementsByTag("tr")
                    For r = 1 To hTR.Count - 1
                    Set hTD = hTR(r).FindElementsByTag("td")
                    If hTD.Count = 0 Then Set hTD = hTD(r).FindElementsByTag("th")
                        lr1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        For c = 2 To hTD.Count + 1
                        .Cells(lr1, c).Value = hTD(c - 1).Text
                        Next c
                        Next r
                    End If
                Next bb
                Exit For
            Next tb
        End With
        Dr.Quit
End Sub
```

Below is the HTML code for reference, which I need to pull.

[image]

The other table that is matching with same class name (which is to be excluded) is show below

[image]

**Issue is**:

1. For both the tables CLASS name is same hence it pull second table if the second class code table exists in the webpage..
2. Based on the Webpage update now im getting new error message "**stale element reference element is not attached to the page document**"

Additional attachment:
[image]

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Does the second table have a div enclosing it with an id of `'check-in-out'`, because you can first narrow (reduce the searchable area) in on the table that you want before trying to find each element.

Comment: @Andrew Ryan, Thanks for the reply, I have added additional attachment for that second table.. Please check if that helps for you..

Comment: Sure this line `If hTD.Count = 0 Then Set hTD = hTD(r).FindElementsByTag("th")` shouldn't be on two lines? Your code won't compile otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from your attachments, both the tables have the same class ie. `".table-basic.check-in-out-table"` But the first table is present below the div tag with `id='check-in-out'` and the second table is present below the div tag with `id='assetDetails'`

So, you can diffrentiate between the two tables based on the div tag within with each of these tables are contained using the below CSS Selectors

```
Table 1 CSS Selector - "#check-in-out .table-basic.check-in-out-table"

Table 2 CSS Selector - "#assetDetails .table-basic.check-in-out-table"
```

Hope this works

Comment: can you suggest me how to overcome the Error message popup "stale element reference element is not attached to the page document"..

Comment: you would need to update your code to shown what you have done so far and also the error logs so that we can check where the issue lies and how can it be fixed. If possible, please also add the url that has these elements. thanks